# How to efficiently compute hamming distances with Vulkan

Tags: gpu, vulkan, hamming-distance

What is an efficient way to calculate hamming distances/popcounts between bit strings (assume 32 or 64 bit integer pointers) on the GPU with the Vulkan API. From what I've seen there is no intrinsic support in the API as there is in i.e. CUDA. Will there possibly be something coming in a future API version or extension?

Comment: `bitCount(a ^ b)`?

Comment: Where exactly does `bitCount` come from? It's not part of the Vulkan API, is it?

Comment: `bitCount` is GLSL function (the `xor` as well).